# Notation of Poynting vector

Tags: physics, electromagnetism

I know that the Poynting vector is defined as the cross-product $\vec{E}\times\vec{H}$ and that is "usually" denoted by $\vec{S}$ or $\vec{N}$.

I wonder if there is a particular reason for these names. I've also seen it indicated with $\vec{P}$ and this makes more sense as it could stand for "Poynting". Do the others refer to something?

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't a particular reason for using $\vec{S}$ or $\vec{N}$.

Comment: Consult his original paper:  Poynting, John Henry (1884). "On the Transfer of Energy in the Electromagnetic Field". Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London. 175: 343–361. doi:10.1098/rstl.1884.0016

Comment: Poynting did not use vector notation, he uses German letters.

Comment: ... and Poynting wrote his equations in coordinates, each vector corresponding to three different letters.  So I did not see a reason for "S" in that paper.

Comment: FWIW it seems like Heaviside used $\mathbf{W}$, see e.g. https://archive.org/details/electricalpapers01heavuoft/page/376/mode/2up
or https://archive.org/details/electricalpapers02heavrich/page/96/mode/2up
(And he was of course very influential with his vector notation.)

Comment: See also this paper, which has citations for early developments by Thomson, Tait, Hertz, Poincare, others: https://physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/poynting_alt.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to Heaviside, notation in electromagnetism was mixed, and vector notation as we know it today was not in use. Rather, equations were often expressed component-wise, although the concept of a vector still existed. Heaviside, who developed much of the modern vector notation we use today, used $\mathbf{W}$ to represent this additional energy term as early as 1884.

For use of $\mathbf{S}$: As noted [in this article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8125229), "Energy in Electromagnetism: The Poynting Vector" published in IEEE Antennas and Propagation Magazine, the notation $\mathbf{S}$ first appeared in H. A. Lorentz's *The Theory of Electrons and Its Applications to the Phenomena of Light and Radiant Heat* (1909) p.23, where he says:

> As to the transfer of energy represented by (39), it must necessarily take place at the points of the surface $\sigma$ itself, because our theory leaves no room for any action at a distance. Further, we are naturally led to suppose that the actions by which it is brought about are such that, for each element $d\sigma$, the quantity $c[\mathbf{d}\cdot\mathbf{h}]_n d\sigma$ may be said to represent the amount of energy that is transmitted across this particular element. In this way we come to the conception, first formulated by Poynting${}^1$, of a *current* or *flow* of energy. It is determined by the vector product of $\mathbf{d}$ and $\mathbf{h}$, multiplied by the constant $c$, so that we can write for it
> $$
> \mathbf{S} = c[\mathbf{d}\cdot\mathbf{h}]\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{(42)}
> $$

Where Lorentz uses $c$ for the speed of light, and $[\ \cdot\ ]$ represents the cross product. He doesn't give any justification for choosing $\mathbf{S}$.

It was not used by some significant physicists, including Max Abraham and Hermann Minkowski, nor was it used by Whittaker in his [History of Theories of the Ether and Electricity](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_history_of_the_theories_of_aether_and/zYx2gQjpe2MC?hl=en&gbpv=0) (1910), see e.g. p.348. But G. H. Livens did use $\mathbf{S}$ in *The Theory of Electricity* (1918), (second edition [available here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/4q45AAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)) which was influential.